# PHP many variables in WHERE clause MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Here I want to add another variable using AND.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * 
            FROM messages WHERE Subject_Code = ' ".$_SESSION['sub1']." ' ");
```

I want to add `Week = ' ".$_SESSION["weekS1"]." '` to this query using AND. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP PDO supports positional (?) and named (:email) placeholders, the latter always begins from a colon and can be written using letters, digits and underscores only. Also note that no quotes have to be ever used around placeholders.

Eg:

The following becomes

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND status='$status'";
```

To

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND status=?';
```

OR

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND status=:status';
```

With placeholders, you have to prepare it, using the PDO::prepare() method

To get the query executed, you must run execute() method of this object, passing variables in it, in the form of array

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND status=?');
$stmt->execute([$email, $status]);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
// or
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND status=:status');
$stmt->execute(['email' => $email, 'status' => $status]);
$user = $stmt->fetch();
```

Very Good Reference for full tutorial : https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: Good example. If you want to add conditions incrementally you can have `$conds = array()` and then append to that and add placeholder values to a secondary array, later combining the query with `implode('AND', $conds)` to assemble the final clause. PDO makes this pretty easy to do incrementally.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP5+, You are supposed to bind your parameters outside of the query string when executing your statement.

Example:

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE Subject_Code = :subj AND Week = :week')
$query->execute(array(
    ':subj' => $_SESSION['sub1'],
    ':week' => $_SESSION["weekS1"],
));
```

Comment: some great examples of this can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: @Mart Please don't link to third-rate sites like w3schools. The official PHP documentation is up-to-date, more thorough, and has a helpful community comments section.